# How do I extend a class?

Tags: java

I have a class: `Model`, with many functions, such as `draw()`, `rotate()` etc.

now i have another class called `Cube` that i want to be able to work the same way as Model.

I have this in my `Cube` class constructor:

```
Model m3d = new Model();        
m3d.build(obj);
```

So what i want is to be able to in another class call something like:

```
mCube.draw();
```

and `m3d` will perform `draw()`.

Comment: (off topic: thanks for editing, couldn't see any output when i wrote the Q for some reason.)

Comment: Subject edited: you extend classes in Java, not objects.

Comment: @Neal, Yes i was trying to do that but there was a count down before i could do that, accepted now. Thanks for editing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok. So do this in the class call:

```
class Cube extends Model {...}
```

Then you can do:

```
Cube mCube = new Cube();        
mCube.build(obj);
mCube.draw();
```